# How can I 'lock' a page behind a log-in screen in jQuery/Bootstrap/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, firebase

I've been building a web app using Google's Firebase as a backend (for those who don't know, it's a Realtime database; any changes in data are reflected instantly and updated), there's other people working on the Android app with it so there's no other option (plus it's kinda cool). I was surprised that I have yet to write a single line of php or any server-side code. Anyway, jQuery is working perfectly fine for login and stuff.

Now I'm going to be making an admin page (with a separate login from the main users login). It'll be accessed in a completely separate way (by opening something like `/admin.html`). So the login can't be put on a separate page so people don't 'accidentally' access the admin panel by writing `/admin.html` in the address bar.

So I want to stop the admin page from completely loading until I've received confirmation from Firebase that the credentials are correct. So how can I achieve this knowing that both the login and the whole admin page needs to be in the same file. I'm positive this can be achieved with simple jQuery + Bootstrap but I'm not really sure how. Can anyone please point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

I *have* googled it of course but maybe my wording is off? :P

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, your problem is that you need to create two separate views in a single file, and redirect to one or to another depending on your user "session", however, as all your code is in client, you don't have a "session" system operative.

Ok, there are several options you can take. I like the idea of using LocalStorage to store the user session.

When /admin.html is requested, your code checks for a valid session object (keep in mind that you'll need to define that session object) in the LocalStorage. If there is a valid object, you render the admin area, if there isn't any, you render the login area.

When someone sends username/pass to the database and you receive a valid response, you create a session object, store it in the LocalStorage and reload the page.

Keep in mind that you'll need to create a mechanism to make sessions die and a log off view.

For the dying sessions, as an idea, you can store the creation time and a expiration time in the session object. Each time a "session protected" page is served, when you check that the session object exist, you update it's expiration date a fixed amount (20 minutes plus current time, for example).

So, when you check if exists a valid session, you also check that it's expiration date has not due, and if it's, you delete the object.

Comment: The 'session' is actually maintained by Firebase itself! So that one login affects all devices, I can detect a login and logout through an event and act accordingly but how do I do that in jQuery? Basically just 2 steps: Load nothing, check Firebase's session, if valid, render admin page, otherwise load login page. Thanks!

Comment: if (loginValid) { adminPageCode(); } else { loginPageCode(); }